# SQL: table contains individual items and FK to lists - return all individual items from table & lists

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I have a table that combines:

- Conditions for auto-emails (FK to table with auto-email UI action triggers)
- Emails for individual users (FK to table with emails)
- Mailing lists (FK to table with mailing lists)

This table allows me to:

- Add individual emails to auto-email triggers
- Add individual emails to mailing lists
- Add mailing lists to auto-email triggers

  - Mailing lists only have individual emails - mailing lists cannot be nested

When I need to send an email from the website, I need to pull all distinct emails for the desired auto-email trigger.  I want individual emails *only*.  For any/all mailing lists assigned to the trigger, I want to return the emails for that mailing list, not the name of the mailing list.

EDIT (updated tables):

Actual DB tables:

User table

```
User_ID   First_Name   Last_Name   Email        Other Info (multiple columns)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         Mike         Smith       mike@me.com   <other info>
2         Sue          Jones       sue@me.com    <other info>
3         Bob          Roberts     bob@me.com    <other info>
4         Mary         Evans       mary@me.com   <other info>
5         Joe          Miller      joe@me.com    <other info>
```

Auto_Email table

```
Auto_Email_ID   Page      Trigger
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               Events    Save Event
2               Events    Edit Event
3               Events    Delete Event
4               Friends   Request Friend
5               Friends   Confirm Friend
```

Mailing_List table

```
Mailing_List_ID   Mailing_List
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 Team A
2                 Team B
3                 Team C
```

Email_List table

```
ID   Auto_Email_ID   User_ID    List_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1               1          NULL
2    1               NULL       1
3    1               NULL       2
4    2               2          NULL
5    2               NULL       3
6    NULL            1          1
7    NULL            3          1
8    NULL            4          2
9    NULL            5          3
```

Email_List view

```
ID   Auto_Email_ID   Trigger         User_ID   Email         List_ID   List
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1               Save Event      1         mike@me.com   NULL      NULL
2    1               Save Event      NULL      NULL          1         Team A
3    1               Save Event      NULL      NULL          2         Team B
4    2               Confirm Friend  2         sue@me.com    NULL      NULL
5    2               Confirm Friend  NULL      NULL          3         Team C
6    NULL            NULL            1         mike@me.com   1         Team A
7    NULL            NULL            3         bob@me.com    1         Team A
8    NULL            NULL            4         mary@me.com   2         Team B
9    NULL            NULL            5         joe@me.com    3         Team C
```

Desired results for Auto_Email condition "Save Event": (from individual emails, Team A emails, and Team B emails):

```
mike@me.com
bob@me.com
mary@me.com
```

I know how to do this with the below code, but that's a lot of loops and calls back to SQL.  I'd prefer to do this with a single SQL proc/query, but I don't know how.

Using vb.Net:

```
Dim sendTo = New List(Of String)

For Each email As MyObject In GetEmailsForAutoEmail("Save Event") 'calls SQL proc
    If (email.Email_ID.HasValue) Then
        sendTo.Add(email.Email)
    Else
        For Each mlEmail As MyObject In GetEmailsForMailingList(email.List) 'calls SQL proc
            sendTo.Add(mlEmail.Email)
        Next
    End If
Next

sendTo = sendTo.Distinct()
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but this strikes me as a terrible database design.

Comment: This is a very convoluted table... Are you displaying columns from several different tables, or is that *actually* how they're stored?  (Please show table structure if they are stored differently than how you're displaying them in your question.)

Comment: I was displaying columns as shown in the DB view - I've added the structure for all involved tables.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the job:

```
SELECT
  email
FROM Usr U
JOIN Email_List E
  ON U.user_ID = E.user_ID
  AND E.list_ID IS NULL
JOIN Auto_Email A
  ON E.auto_Email_ID = A.auto_Email_ID
  AND A.triggr = 'Save Event'
UNION
SELECT
  email
FROM Usr U
JOIN Email_List E1
  ON U.user_ID = E1.user_ID
  AND E1.auto_Email_ID IS NULL
JOIN Email_List E2
  ON E1.list_ID = E2.list_ID
  AND E1.auto_Email_ID IS NULL
  AND E2.user_ID IS NULL
JOIN Mailing_List M
  ON E2.list_ID = M.mailing_List_ID
  AND E2.user_ID IS NULL
JOIN Auto_Email A
  ON E2.auto_Email_ID = A.auto_Email_ID
  AND E2.user_ID IS NULL
  AND A.triggr = 'Save Event'
;
```

It `UNION`s the individually listed users with the users, signed up via some list(s).

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba162/1).

For simpler SQL / better readability (and possibly slightly better performance), the **Email_List** table would probably better be split into two or three tables:

- **User_List** matching users and lists, and
- one (each) for users and lists to align to **Auto_Email**.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: @steelerose Did you have a chance to check, whether this is going anywhere close to what you were looking for?